# Temporary Storage for Fixed result coming from Web API Post Action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Master Table where records are Fixed and changing probability is very less. So I am thinking to place it in some Temporary Storage. The table resultant is like below

```
_______________
|ID   |Name    |
----------------
|1    |Open    |
|2    |Closed  |
|3    |Pending |
----------------
```

Right now I am fetching the result from Web-API. So every time it goes to Database to fetch these three records.

> Question: As Web API has no In-built Caching mechanism. Should I use
>   Cache or Cookies to store the above result-set ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your resultset inside the [WebCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webcache%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

In general, you use it like this:

```
var result = System.Web.Helpers.WebCache.Get('keyToYourData');
if (result == null) 
{
    // cache wasn't created yet, create it and set it into the cache
    result = LoadMyData();
    System.Web.Helpers.WebCache.Set('keyToYourData', result);
}
return result;
```

This would first check if there is data inside your WebCache, if not, you will get the data from your database, set the data in your cache for future request and return the data.

> This class represents a helper, which is a component that simplifies web programming in ASP.NET Web Pages. Use the WebCache class to cache frequently accessed data, which can improve website performance. Information that is often accessed but rarely changed is a good candidate for caching.

Comment: I think It will be stored on server ? and another question is: Will this value be stored separately for each session on server ?

Comment: @Pankaj Well yes, it would be stored on the server, but it wouldn't need any database access, it would serve it from memory. You could ofcourse do it with local storage inside the clients browser, but then you would also have to think of a way to synchronize that data in case something does change in the table. The data would be shared for all your users, not per session, so every user would see the same data coming from 1 source

Comment: I checked in MSDN about it and found that I can't set the auto expiry date while Creating the key. So this will not be beneficial at all.

Comment: @Pankaj no, but when it changes, you can reset the value on the server which would change for all new requests as soon as you change it

Comment: This is not at all a reliable process.Why ? Because I want to set the value live for max few hours and then when it expires will go to database automatically. At-least when it expires will go to database otherwise there is no chance for automatic updates...Thoughts ?

Comment: If you choose to only set your cache on the server, then it is perfectly safe, you are getting a cache if it's there, if not you go to the database. If you change anything on the database at this level (which is unlikely as you said) you should make sure that the cache gets cleared again (doesn't need to be set). The WebCache does recycle every so often, so it will go back to the database eventually

Comment: Is there any recommended technique to save this on client side instead on server ?